# Return statement in python function not returning anything

Tags: python

I don't understand the difference between return and print. I was told that you should use return in function statements but it doesn't return anything, so I've been using print in my functions. But I want to understand why return statements in my functions do not work.

```
def triangle_area(b, h):
    return 0.5 * b * h

triangle_area(20, 10)
```

I would expect this return the multiplication, but it doesn't yield anything. Please help! And when I replace the return with print, it works perfectly. Am i supposed to use print in functions?

Comment: `print(triangle_area(20, 10))` ?

Comment: You should do `print(triangle_area(20, 10))`.

Comment: You need to either print the output, or assign it to a variable. `x=triangle_area(20, 10)` then you can use or print `x`

Comment: And 7 answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` and `print` are two very different instructions. [Return](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/global_&_return.html) has the purpose of **storing** the value that is computed by a function, value that will be used according to the programmer's wish. [Print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) does what it says: it prints whatever you tell him to print.

Using `return` won't print anything, because this instruction is not built for such a purpose. Only for **storing**. Nothing more, nothing less. `print` displays something on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
print(triangle_area(20, 10))
```

**Good luck to you all, bro!**

Answer (score 0):

It *does* return the product; what it *doesn't* do is print it (since you didn't tell it to).

Comment: I think OP doesn't understand what returning or printing is

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not printing the return result from the function. Please try:

```
print(traingle_area(20,30))
```

Comment: I think OP doesn't understand what returning or printing is

Answer (score 0):

You are not receiving the output the function is returning.

```
print(triangle_area(20, 10))
```

This will show the result.

Answer (score 0):

Functions return a value, so you need to store them in variable.

`print(triangle_area(20, 10))`

Answer (score 0):

It is returning the value, you simply are not capturing it or doing anything with it. For instance:

```
def triangle_area(b, h):
    return 0.5 * b * h

output = triangle_area(20, 10) # capture return value
print(output)
```

Or as others have suggested, just pass the result straight to the `print` function if that's what you're looking to do:

```
def triangle_area(b, h):
    return 0.5 * b * h

print(triangle_area(20, 10)) # capture return value and immediately pass to print function
```

Note that the output will be lost if passed straight to `print()`. If you want to use it later in your program, the first code block is more appropriate